# bug: javafx webengine getelementbyid return null inside a thread

Tags: java, debugging, webview, javafx, getelementbyid

Edit: added screenshot

i have a problem with javafx.
I need to get a element from the document but when i write this code inside a thread it returns null on getelementbyid

Works:

```
        scanprofilesbutton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {

        if (engine.getLocation().contains("events")) {
            if (engine.getDocument() == null) {
                System.out.println("null");
            }

            Element el = engine.getDocument().getElementById("nav-profile");
            System.out.println("You are logged in as " + el.getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent().trim());
        }            
    });
```

Exception (java.lang.NullPointerException):

```
        scanprofilesbutton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (engine.getLocation().contains("events")) {
                        if (engine.getDocument() == null) {
                            System.out.println("null");
                        }

                        Element el = engine.getDocument().getElementById("nav-profile");
                        Exception ->> System.out.println("You are logged in as " + el.getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent().trim());                         
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    });
```

I'm stuck on this and i didn't found any solution. Thanks!

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: post the whole error log sir

Comment: @Elltz it only says nullpointerexception and the number of the line

Comment: So which line is it?

Comment: @dejuknow System.out.println("You are logged in as " + el.getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent().trim());

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1) `engine.getDocument().getElementById("nav-profile")` is returning null so your `Element el` is null.

OR

2) something in the chained call below is returning null, perhaps your `.item(1)` method (did you mean `.item(0)`)?

```
el.getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()
```

Instead of polling every five seconds, the better solution would be to attach a listener to the load worker and only check when the webpage has successfully loaded. See the API for an [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

Comment: The first example works fine outside the thread so i think it's not the code but something else happening when inside the thread. getDocument() inside the thread is not null but when i try to do the same thing i do outside it gives nullpointerexception

Comment: Element el = engine.getDocument().getElementById("nav-profile");                 

this returns null but outside the thread it works

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood when it comes to dealing with JavaFX, the FX Application main thread is responsible for controlling JavaFX objects directly and other threads are disallowed. In this particular case this caused NullPointerException to be thrown, in other cases `'Not on FX application thread'` would probably be seen. To solve this problem the `Platform.runLater(runnableObject)` should be used.